# how to dynamic change div content onclick of button with mysql variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a problem with some dynamic buttons, these buttons are generated by a while loop:

```
while($sub_row=mysqli_fetch_array($piano_query)){ 
    $piano=$sub_row['piano'];
    $prezzo_piano=$sub_row['prezzo'];
    $id_appartamenti=$sub_row['id_appartamenti'];

    echo '<button type="button" class="simple-text piano" id="'.$id_appartamenti.'">piano '.$piano.'<br></button>';
```

So now, I want that when I click on those buttons (the id is set from a variable) something changes in a div.
So I used a JavaScript, and I've tried to insert a php echo for the ID but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<?php echo $id_appartamenti?> ").click(function() {
        document.getElementById("prezzo").innerHTML="<?php echo $prezzo_piano;?> €";
    });
})
```

and then something as to happen in the div with id=prezzo:

```
<div class="paragraph" id="prezzo">something has to happen here €</div>
```

Comment: You mention that "it doesn't work". What does it do then? Do you have any error in the browser console? Show us the rendered/client-side HTML/JS code!

Comment: You should do this with `data` attributes and `class` handlers, instead of making a js click handler for every `id` element dynamically.

Comment: You're setting the ID from the `$prezzo_piano` variable, but you're adding the event listener on the ID from `$id_appartamenti` and in it, you replace the text in the button to the value of `$prezzo_piano`? That seems... odd. However, I would recommend you to do it as @IncredibleHat suggests. No need for separate event handlers for each button.

Comment: yes, there was an error, i want to recall the  ID=id_appartamenti and the event listener is the same...

Comment: hi @IncredibleHat, how can i do that? sorry, but i've just started with php and js

Comment: hi @sjahan, no error in the browser console.. but, since i'm new to php I want to know if it's possible to insert an echo php inside a javascript..

Comment: Posted you an example using your values. It may work, but since I was unsure the actual data in your values, I added extra sanitize code for the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to use `data` attributes and `class` for a single event handler that controls them all (you can remove the linebreaks in the echo... I put them in for stackoverflow easier reading):

```
while($sub_row=mysqli_fetch_array($piano_query)) {
    echo '<button type="button" 
           class="event-hook-class simple-text piano" 
           id="'. $sub_row['id_appartamenti'] .'" 
           data-prezzo="'. htmlspecialchars($sub_row['prezzo'],ENT_QUOTES) .'" 
          >piano '. htmlspecialchars($sub_row['piano']) .'</button><br>';
}

echo '<div class="paragraph" id="prezzo">Placeholder €</div>';
```

Your script (only one block, not duplicated):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".event-hook-class").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#prezzo").html( $(this).data('prezzo') +' €' );
    });
});
```

Using the magical `$(this)` refers to only the button that was clicked at that time. Then you reference the `data` attribute with `.data('prezzo')`. That attribute contains an html safe value (since I was unsure what was exactly in that variable).